# Get mean values if a key column value is duplicated with dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data. What I would like to do is, if the gene column has duplicated value (e.g. `CASZ1`), then I would like to get mean values for each Sample column.

Input data

[image]

Output data

[image]

I googled it and tried, but I am stuck to get an answer. I am sorry for asking such a question looks exactly like homework.

My code

```
data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(avg = mean(colnames(data)) --- error...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `summarise_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

Comment: Thank you! I should read more about dplyr.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `summarize_at` along with some regular expression to ensure any column not starting by your pattern will not be included:

```
data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise_at(vars(matches("Sample")), mean)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I can use regex in dplyr. Good to know.